# bad file descriptor C

Tags: c

Im working on a program that gets file through argument and returns its information and name. Im getting error Bad file description. My code look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
        {
            int file = 0;
            file = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
            if(file == -1)
            {
                close(file);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                struct stat info;
                if(fstat(file, &info) < 0)
                {
                    close(file);
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Status information for %s\n",argv[i]);
                    printf("Size of file: %d \n", info.st_size);
                    printf("Number of connections: %d\n", info.st_nlink);   
                    printf("inode: %d\n", info.st_ino);                 
                    printf("Last used : %s", ctime(&info.st_atime));
                    printf("Last change : %s", ctime(&info.st_mtime));
                    printf("Last status of change : %s", ctime(&info.st_ctime));
                    printf("ID owner : %d\n", info.st_uid);
                    printf("ID group : %d\n", info.st_gid);
                    printf("ID device : %d\n", info.st_dev);
                    printf("Security : :");
                    printf((S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
                    printf((info.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
                    if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode)){
                        printf("\nFile is regular\n");
                    }
                    else if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)){
                        printf("\nFile is a directory\n");
                    }
                    printf("\n===================================\n");
                    close(file);

                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i run program like this for example:
./program somefile
i get this in return --> Bad file descriptor

Comment: try googling first before coming here, there are tons of answeres out there

Comment: If `open` fails, why would you try to `close` the result? It only returns -1 on error because that _can't_ be a valid file descriptor, and so _cannot_ be valid to `close`.

Comment: Where do you see that error?

Comment: thanks useless that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        file = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        if(file == -1)
        {
            close(file);
            return 1;
        }
```

because, when `file==-1`, it isn't a valid file descriptor to pass to `close`.

You can reassure yourself that it's ok not to call `close` in this branch, because if `open` failed, there *is* nothing to `close` in the first place.

As an aside, `close` also has a return value, and both `open` and `close` set `errno` if they fail: you can check for, and log, all of these. The fact that almost all the code ends up being error checking/handling, is one of the motivations for other languages (like C++) introducing exceptions.

```
int file = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
if(file == -1) {
    perror("open failed");
    return 1;
}
struct stat info;
if (fstat(file, &info) < 0) {
    perror("fstat failed");
    if (close(file) < 0) {
        perror("close failed");
    }
    return 1;
}
```